# How can I make my mobile site text size appear the same size as my desktop site?

Tags: text, mobile, size

I need to use the same code for my mobile site as my desktop site (below). How can I enlarge my mobile site's text size so it looks the same as my desktop site?

This is my header info and title:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
```

This is my Cascading Style Sheet data:

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

A:link {text-decoration: none;} 
A:visited {text-decoration: none;} 
A:hover {text-decoration: underline;} 

img {
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
} 

table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}

td {word-wrap: break-word;}

--> 
  </style>
  </head>
```

This is my cream background colour:

```
  <body style="background-color: rgb(255, 239, 227);">
```

This is the content of my site, where I would insert text between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags:

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <table width="80%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p>
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>

    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following code before the `</head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This makes the text size appear the same size as your desktop site.